# How to Upload Publish files in azure web apps using PowerShell Scripts

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Previously uploading publish files to azure web apps using FileZilla .but i am trying 2 or more files uploading to azure web apps using powershell scripts now.please help me any power shell script .

Answer (score 0):

> but i am trying 2 or more files uploading to azure web apps using powershell scripts now.please help me any power shell script.

I assumed that you could use powershell script for deploying your web app code using FTP (via [WebClient.UploadFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms144229.aspx)) and recursively upload your publish files as follows:

```html
# Upload files recursively 
Set-Location $appdirectory
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appdirectory -Recurse | Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)}
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")
    "Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()
```

For more details, you could refer to [Upload files to a web app using FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/scripts/app-service-powershell-deploy-ftp).

Additionally, you could [Using KUDU with Microsoft Azure Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/), click "Debug Console > PowerShell or CMD" to open a console, then `cd site\wwwroot` to the web content of your web app, then you could drag your publish files, and drop them directly into the Kudu console's file explorer UI for uploading files. For more details, you could refer to [Kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) about uploading files.